# How to use selector select html element's attribute?

Tags: python, regex, css-selectors, web-crawler, scrapy

Currently, I am using Scrapy.

The selector works fine when matching

```
<xxx>  something to match </xxx>
```

But I want to match

```
<xxx name="something I want match"> xxx </xxx>
```

What I want to match is inside the element tag.

I know Regex is one solution. Is there a easier way doing so.

Comment: [Go to the docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html) and scroll to `Now we’re going to get the base URL and some image links:`.

Comment: I read this before. What confused me is how to match something inside the tag.

Comment: A wild guess : `sel.css('xyz::attr(name)').extract()`

Comment: @HamZa: Talk about misleading documentation. `::text` and `::attr()` are non-standard pseudo-elements used by Scrapy - it says they are "CSS3 pseudo-elements", but they are not.

Comment: @BoltClock Too much jQuery these days :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found 2 ways doing so:

```
1.sel.xpath('//baseTag/@attrName')
2.sel.css('baseTag::attr(attrName)')
```

[see more](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#topics-selectors-htmlcode)